# Standardized bivariate regression coefficients >1?

Tags: statistics, regression

x and y are two columns of financial data which have been standardized. Assuming one implements a simple linear regression on x and y, is it possible to observe a slope greater than 1?

I ran some numbers in Excel and cannot get the slope to ever exceed 1. Can someone please explain the mathematical reason why this is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *standardised* represents location and scale changes forcing each mean to $0$ and standard deviation to $1$

then the simple least-squares linear regression line should have zero intercept and a slope equal to the correlation, which must be somewhere in the interval $[-1,1]$.

If you had not standardised, the slope would have been $r_{xy} \dfrac{s_y}{s_x}$  but you have made $s_y=s_x=1$.

Comment: Thank you. What is the intuition behind this? I am still having difficulty seeing why we can see a change of 1 standard deviation in x correspond to a, say, 2 standard deviation in y.

Comment: @KingSquirrel I do not understand your example: if you regress $y$ as the dependent variable on $x$ as the independent variable then your model will predict that a $1$ standard deviation change in $x$ should lead to a change of no more than $1$ standard deviation in the predicted value of $y$ .  That corresponds to saying that $|r_{x,y}|  \le 1$